# Make in Excel "Remained 20/5" via TEXT()

Tags: microsoft-excel

There are 2 columns. One is the number of max days available, and the other is number of days spent.

```
Max     Spent
20        1
```

I would like to format Max to says `20/DaysRemained` (`DaysRemained` should be replaced with the value of actual remaining days). I tried to make a formula like `="20/"&TEXT(20-D3)` where D3 contains number of days spent.

The formula does not seem to work as I am obviously missing something.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Since you posted that you don't want what you say you want, can you please edit your question and give an example of the expected result in context. Maybe mock it up manually in Excel and post a screenshot. That may be better than using words.

Comment: @teylyn I did not write it wrongly, but it seems that I used too much programming vocabulary. `DaysRemained` to a programmer means `enter here value a value of how many days remained`

Comment: Right. Take a look at my suggestions, below. I removed all the misleading bits about formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Text() function formats a number to text, but it requires a formatting string. So maybe change your formula:

```
="20/"&TEXT(20-D3,"0")
```

or just use

```
="20/"&20-D3
```

You can also reference to the value in the cell like

```
=C3&"/"&C3-D3
```

In Excel, the & operator accepts both text and numbers and the result will always be text.

Comment: I did not ask this. I asked how I can replace DaysRemained with deduction of 20 and D3 cell. The answer is `="20/"&20- D3`

Comment: you asked "I would like to format Max to says 20/DaysRemained". If that is not what you want, please edit your question and ask about what you really want to do.

Comment: I took another guess at what you may want and added suggestions to my answer.

Comment: Is this possible without helper column?

Comment: @Vylix No. You can't have a value and a formula in the same cell. If you want to subtract from a value with a formula, then that formula needs to be in a different cell. Manipulating the original cell value can be done with VBA, but changing the cell value without a trace of what changed it would be very, very bad data architecture.

Comment: Btw, seems you misplaced your formula. It makes no sense to have 20/19, rather I think op wants 19/20 instead.

Comment: @Vylix not according to the OP's formula attempt and description. It's hard to get a reply out of the OP, though. I've been trying for a while ... Maybe you can post another approach and may have better luck. Nothing like talking to a brick wall.

Answer (score 0):

### Note

This is possible because you have "Max" value, which I assume is fixed and won't change, thus there are only limited number of values (0-20) that can be handled by using Conditional Formatting.

**Disclaimer:** Although this partially satisfy OP's requirement, this is **an ugly** approach. I do not recommend because you'll need to literally write 20 (21, exactly) custom formats (or more or less, if the 'max' value changes), and write them again if 'max' changes.

This formats the "Spent" cell, not "Max" cell as OP requested. This is as close I can suggest.

---

1. Open **Conditional Formatting**, and select **New Rule**
2. Put `=A1=0` on the formula box. Change `A1` to the address of "Spent" cell.
3. Open **Format**, then select **Custom** on *Numbers* tab.
4. Put `0"/20"` as the custom format. This formula is fixed throughout the iteration.
5. Repeat step 1 to 4 for each value from 0 to 20 (0, 1, 2, ... , 20)

You'll end up with 21 conditional formatting. You can also change the custom format to what you are requesting on the question (which becomes `"20/"0`), though I find it confusing.
[image: Screenshot]